# Register two .NET COM-visible assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, com, guid, com-interop

I am trying to create two independent .NET COM visible assemblies for the same object. One is registered by our installer, and the other one on a per user basis - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2007/02/21/per-user-com-registrations-and-elevated-processes-with-uac-on-windows-vista.aspx.

Do I need to change the GUIDs for all the classes in the second assembly and would this create any confusion for COM clients as to which class belongs to which assembly?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It will certainly create massive confusion, there's just no need to do this.

Comment: There is no need to install the COM object on a per user basis if it is installed at the machine level.  Follow the last line of the article that you linked: "So, if you are an application developer who is designing an application to run elevated, you should make sure that you drop your COM registrations in the per-machine hive (which creating a new key in HKCR will do by default) at install time, rather than relying on a per-user installation."

Comment: Thank you for your input.
The reason behind the two assemblies - the second assembly will be updated much more frequently by a Silverlight component that can only update HKCU. Only that Silverlight component will use the second assembly. I need to be able to have the two assemblies side by side.

Comment: One more clarification. I abandoned the Reg-free COM because it doesn't work in a folder other than the executable path. See my post on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154432/can-a-silverlight-component-instantiate-a-registration-free-com-visible-net-obj/18358832#18358832

Comment: @rgeorg - why does the Silverlight application need to register the .NET assembly for COM interop?  Can't it just call the assembly directly?

Comment: @shf301 Because this way we can deploy it more frequently in order to be able to add new features without waiting for a client package release.Thanks